# Application was removed by system (Android - java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-8.0-oreo, android-9.0-pie

I wrote an app for android system in java. I have used firebase to deliver notification. It works on all phones but on some it shows notification (we had cases on android 9 at least) "application was removed by system" on a start and on the end application is not removed. Any idea why? How to fix that?

[customer phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4x1J.png)

```
Details: Compile target: SDK 28 min android: 5.0
Phones:
sony xperia xz1 - android 9
sony xperia xz2 - android 9
Samsung Galaxy A5 (2017) - Android version 8.0.0. Samsung Experience version 9.0
```

I have tried to find some information on internet but no luck till now.

Comment: Its been uploaded to playstore or directly to customers phone they can just allow the unkown sources to their settings

Comment: Customer got his app from playstore.